# YouTube Direct AuthSub malformed request

Tags: google-app-engine, youtube-api, authsub

I'm using the YouTube Direct for Google App Engine. I go into the Admin section to authenticate my account, but when I do that, instead of logging me in, it redirects me to a page saying:

> "The page you have requested cannot be displayed. Another site was
>   requesting access to your Google Account, but sent a malformed
>   request. Please contact the site that you were trying to use when you
>   received this message to inform them of the error."

I'm pretty sure I setup my configuration properly. I even setup secure authsub so that when a user logs into his Youtube account through the app it says that the connection is secure. However, whenever I want to authenticate myself in the admin section, it gives me that malformed request. To avoid ambiguity, this is where I am trying to authenticate:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ten4h.png

Here is the request, if that helps:

[http://www.youtube.com/auth_sub_request?scope=http%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com&session=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Figivemoretest.appspot.com%2Fadmin%2FPersistAuthSubToken&secure=0](http://www.youtube.com/auth_sub_request?scope=http://gdata.youtube.com&session=1&next=http://igivemoretest.appspot.com/admin/PersistAuthSubToken&secure=0)

I guess it's trying to access some info from my Google account and forward it to my App engine instance to the URL http://igivemoretest.appspot.com/admin/PersistAuthSubToken&secure=0

Comment: We can't possibly figure out what you're doing wrong without seeing your code. Also, please embed images in your question - external URLs tend to decay.

Comment: I'm using an unmodified version of YouTube-Direct(Java version). http://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Google account was not properly linked with Youtube. I'm not sure why this happens, but it happens with all my Google apps accounts. It works if I just create a regular Google account and use it.